# How to get NSStream total length?

Tags: objective-c, stream

I want to know, if there an easy way to get the total length in bytes of the NSStream object. So, for example, in C# I can get a `Stream.Length` property, and that'll be the answer. In objective-c, so far, I haven't found anything like that. The simplest solution, I could imagine would be "read bytes to buffer and count their number":

```
long totalLength = 0;
while((result = [sInput read:buffer maxLength:BUFFER_SIZE]) != 0) {
        if(result > 0) {
            totalLength += result;
        }
```

As stated in docs return value for read method is:

> A positive number indicates the number of bytes read;
>
> 0 indicates that the end of the buffer was reached;
>
> A negative number means that the operation failed.

finally the size values would contain the total length.

Is this a correct way to solve the issue, or is there a simpler way? Btw, is my code correct? (I'm not confident in my obj-c skills yet)

Comment: What kind of stream do you have? Reading from a regular file, from a TCP socket, ... ?

Comment: @MartinR, I think, I understand my mistake. For some reason, I thought, objective-c would have the same behavior as C#. My question was actually about processing byte array from Http response. In C# it's made with Stream class, so I thought, in objective-c it would be the same. But obj-c uses NSData class for such cases(which has length property), not NSStream. Sorry about misleading.